# SFTP ignores public key

Tags: ssh, public-key, openssh

I have a server setup to only allow private/public keys, except for an SFTP group:

```
Match Group sftp
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    ChrootDirectory %h
```

That works fine, however, I have a user that wants to use SFTP with public key. I have that user set up and SSH works perfectly fine, however, when I add the user to the "sftp" group, authentication stops. I do not want this user to be able to SSH in and I want to Chroot them to their home directory.

I checked that root owns the home directory and that it's not writeable by other groups. The following debugging info isn't leading me anywhere useful either:

```
sftp -vv -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa testuser@serveraddress
```

Gives the following:

```
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
tester@serveraddress's password:
```

Any ideas why it seems to be just completely ignoring the key? Again, if I remove the user from the "sftp" group, logging in with key works fine.

Comment: Check the content of server error log. It should give you a clue what went wrong. It does not look like it igneres private key, but the public key is not recognized on the server.

Comment: Server logs don't seem to show anything useful, unless I'm looking in the wrong spot (checked /var/log/secure and /var/log/messages). If I remove the user from the 'sftp' group, SSH and SFTP work perfectly fine. As soon as I add the user to the group, it fails to work. I also added RSAAuthentication yes and PubKeyAuthentication yes to the Match Group sftp, just to explicitly allow them, if needed. That also made no difference (yes, I restarted sshd after that).

Comment: Also, checked AuthorizedKeysFile and even explicitly set it in the Match Group sftp section. Again, no dice.

Comment: so it is time to try to run server in debug mode and check what is failing.